# Order and nesting of entities in JSON-LD Framing

Tags: json, rdf, json-ld

Given a JSON-LD containing entities of different types, can JSON-LD framing allow to control the order of these entities in the output ? and is it possible to nest (using @nest) some entities to group them ?

Given the input from the playground:

```
{
  "@context": "https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
  "@type": "Create",
  "actor": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "acct:sally@example.org",
    "name": "Sally"
  },
  "object": {
    "@type": "Note",
    "content": "This is a simple note"
  },
  "published": "2015-01-25T12:34:56Z"
}
```

I would like to achieve this, **with the garantee that the Persons will be after the Activity** :

```
{
  "@context": "https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "type": "Create",
      "actor": "acct:sally@example.org",
      "object": {
        "type": "Note",
        "content": "This is a simple note"
      },
      "published": "2015-01-25T12:34:56Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "acct:sally@example.org",
      "type": "Person",
      "name": "Sally"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following framing does what I want, but does not offer a garantee on order: (I tried with `["Person","Create"]` and I still get the Activity before the Person)

```
{
  "@context": "https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
  "type": ["Person", "Create"],
  "actor": {
    "@embed" : "@never",
    "@omitDefault": true
  }
}
```

And, can I nest persons in a `persons` key ? like this:

```
{
  "@context": "https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "type": "Create",
      "actor": "acct:sally@example.org",
      "object": {
        "type": "Note",
        "content": "This is a simple note"
      },
      "published": "2015-01-25T12:34:56Z"
    },
    "actors": [
      {
        "id": "acct:sally@example.org",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "Sally"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, ordering of values in JSON is limited to array values. In particular, keys in a Map structure do not have any inherent order in JSON. The JSON-LD algorithms will generally try to process keys in the order they are seen, but this doesn't include the use cases you are concerned with.

If the option for ordering keys is used, keys are ordered alphabetically.

In the case you cite, the "Note" is actually contained as the type of a key under "Create", so what you might want is to be sure that the object with type "Person" comes after the object with type "Create", but again, there's unfortunately no way to specify this, even though the values are ordered.

Your last example is actually invalid markup, as it is an array, but the second member of the array has a key/value pair.

Comment: Thanks @gregg-kellogg and good to see you here. A followup question, if I may: does JSON-LD framing can take advantage of "@nest" annotation ? (to recreate some intermediate nodes) I suspect no, but would like to confirm. And really, really, what I would need in next version of framing is this : https://github.com/w3c/json-ld-framing/issues/38 - will ask a separate question.

Comment: `@nest` is a compaction attribute. Framing is done after expansion, which will unfold the `@nest`, and can also be specified in the frame context, which will re-do the nesting. So, yes, it can/should work. Best place to experiment is at https://json-ld.org/playground.