# JSON-LD framing : Is it possible to use @nest in @context framing to wrap properties in a "section"?

Tags: json, rdf, json-ld

(followup of [Order and nesting of entities in JSON-LD Framing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73436838/order-and-nesting-of-entities-in-json-ld-framing))

I would like to use `@nest` in JSON-LD framing to group related properties inside a "section" in my output section.

Input JSON-LD :

```
{

  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "id": "http://exemple.fr/me",
  "type": "Person",
  "birthDate" : "1980-09-22",
  "deathDate" : "not yet"

}
```

The output I want is:

```
{
  "@context": "... ?? ...",
  "id": "http://exemple.fr/me",
  "type": "Person",
  "dates": {
    "birthDate" : "1980-09-22",
    "deathDate" : "not yet"
  }
}
```

with the `dates` key mapped to `@nest`.

I can't get this to work on the JSON-LD playground. Is it possible to achieve this using framing ?